# Send an email with a variable defined in another file

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer, php-include

I have file html like *example.php*

```
Url <a href="<? echo $var ?>"><? echo $var ?></a>
```

and i want send mail with this file with variable defined in *send.php*

```
<?php
$var = "someurl";
$contents = file_get_contents("example.php");
mail("x@x.com", "x", $contents");
?>
```

And my problem is this that send.php send `Url <a href="<? echo $var ?>"><? echo $var ?></a>`
instead

> Url someurl

where someurl is hyperlink.

I tried with fread() but the effect is the same.

Anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Php's output buffering and an include:

```
<?php
$var = "someurl";
ob_start();
include 'example.php';
$contents = ob_get_clean();
mail("x@x.com", "x", $contents);
?>
```